# Suddenly all HttpResponseRedirect( reverse() ) are giving syntax errors

Tags: python, django

This one has me scratching my head. I have an app with views that do form processing (logins/signup) and then return various `HttpResponseRedirect()`s based on the input. All of those redirects contain `reverse()` lookups with the appropriate functions listed as strings. And every function has a corresponding `urlpattern` in urls.py.

Everything was working fine until this morning.

Now, whenever I submit a form, Django gives me a syntax error for a non-existent line:

```
SyntaxError at /logout/
invalid syntax (views.py, line 399)
```

(That file only has 354 lines)

When I scroll down to look at the traceback, the line that's highlighted is always one with a `return HttpResponseRedirect( reverse('app.views.func') )`.

Because of these bewildering error messages, I'm not even sure that the problem is really with the `HttpResponseRedirect( reverse() )`s. I haven't touched any of that code in a few days, so I'm not sure why it would suddenly start throwing out weird errors like that.

Any help debugging this would be much appreciated!

Comment: are you using django's auth system?

Comment: Non existent line? Try deleting your compiled python files.. try `find  /my/project/ -name *.pyc | xargs rm`

Comment: Sounds like your script isn't accessing the file you intended it to access. Try renaming your `views.py` to `_views.py` and check whether Django complains about a missing file (maybe there's a different file in another directory, or something).

Comment: @YujiTomita @bitmask I deleted `*.pyc` and renamed the `views.py`. Django complained that it couldn't import them, so I renamed them back, and now I'm still getting the same issue.

Comment: @FrantzdyRomain yah, I'm using django's built-in auth system to handle  authenticated sessions.

Comment: I've even tried reverting back to some of the older commits where I know everything was working, and I'm still getting errors.

Comment: if you can post your code it would be good as well

Comment: figured it out! will write a full answer after class, but see the first note under https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/urls/#reverse for a teaser. there was another unfinished view i am working on that was getting imported by `reverse()`, and that was generating the syntax error.

Comment: sweet! glad you found it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured it out after [consulting the docs for the `reverse()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/urls/#reverse) function.

When you call `reverse()`, django first imports your project's URLConf files, which in turn imports every single view module that is declared in your URLconf. My issue was that I was working on a new, totally unrelated view that had a syntax error (on line 399!).

So even though I wasn't viewing a page that was doing anything with the new view, my old view was still getting tripped up with the syntax error because of how `reverse()` works.

From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/urls/#reverse):

> Make sure your views are all correct. As part of working out which URL
>   names map to which patterns, the reverse() function has to import all
>   of your URLconf files and examine the name of each view. This involves
>   importing each view function. If there are any errors whilst importing
>   any of your view functions, it will cause reverse() to raise an error,
>   even if that view function is not the one you are trying to reverse.
>
> Make sure that any views you reference in your URLconf files exist and
>   can be imported correctly. Do not include lines that reference views
>   you haven't written yet, because those views will not be importable.